# Stanford NLP get the word contribution

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am fairly new to Natural Language Processing, but I need to dig in anyway. I am working with stanford NLP 3.7.0. I need to compute a few things and for that I need the word-contribution from the sentence for each word. So let's say the sentence is: "I am an idiot".

And the word contribution could be like: ("I" : 5, "am" : 2, "an": 0, "idiot" : 10). That's just an example.
And the total contribution could be

```
(5+2+0+10)/4; /*number of words(Just an example) */
```

If I have it correctly I am using the

```
Constituent.score();
```

method to get the score of this word. This method returns a double.

However; I am not sure what exactly is the result computed against, and basically how is this score deduced? Also, what are the maximum and minimum values I can get. I tried googling for this, but could not find anything specific. Maybe you guys can help.

p.s. If it is important, I am working with Java.

Thank You

Comment: Do you mean the score for sentiment ?

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp yeah the score for the sentiment, but not the sentence sentiment, the word-contribution towards the sentence sentiment